# How to enable text selection in a D3.js-SVG that has zoom enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm new with D3 and I going crazy with this detail: I'm building a graph which is a Bubble graph with some labels inside, and I would like to enable users to be able to select the textual labels of the bubbles. I mean, in the traditional way, as if they are highlighting any other text in a webpage.

By default, the graph allows users to select the text in the bubbles, but if I enable the zoom, I can no longer select the texts. I enabled the zoom by:

```
var svg = d3
      .select(this.domSelector)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("class", "bubble")
      .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
            svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
      }))
```

I tried to temporally disable this effect by preventing it if the user is clicking any element byt the background. This is to say:

```
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", (evt) => {
     if(d3.event.sourceEvent.target.tagName.toLocaleLowerCase() == "svg"){
         svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
     }
     else svg.on('.zoom', null); }))
```

But the behaviour is the same: I can not select the text. Any idea?

https://jsfiddle.net/gal007/e2gsvkLt/

Comment: Wonder if the d3 event listeners can be disabled just for the text elements? But then, it's nice if they're not. FYI, in the fiddle before click-to-zoom the text was unselectable. Maybe a little hover/focus on the text that presents a "copy" button?

Comment: You can assign `mousedown` event to text element with `d3.event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Here is Flash's idea: https://jsfiddle.net/vc4epkw5/. @FlashThunder, you should write it as a proper answer: given the very specific scenario of this question I'm pretty sure this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you both! Yes, you should post it as an answer :)

Comment: I can post it as an answer, but not really satisfied with selecting the text by dragging. Tried every event I found to make it more smooth, but couldn't find the perfect solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign `mousedown` event to the text element with `d3.event.stopPropagation()`. Would be something like that:

```
  generateBubbleNames(nodes){
    var maxCharacters = 10;
    var labels = nodes.selectAll("text.label")
    .data(function(d) { return [d]; });

    labels.enter().append("text")
      .attr({
      "class": "label",
      dy: "0.35em"
    })
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.r / 3; })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d[0]
    })
    .on("mousedown", function(){
      d3.event.stopPropagation();
    })
  }
```

Here's a working example:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t59mdu2s/)